# Not sure how to isolate proxy from a database connection

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance, proxy, domain-driven-design

I have the following:

- An Abstract Person object
- A Person object that inherits from the abstract
- A Person proxy object that inherits from the abstract, and has one extra field since this is essentially a friend
- A Person Repository and DAO that fetch everything I need

Here's the problem. At the time I retrieve one person's data, I can retrieve a list of IDs which is their friends list. If I build those Objects right after i fetch the person, that's too expensive. So I built a proxy to be a placeholder. However I still need a database connection to retrieve the data when I need to use it. How exactly do I populate the proxy's internal Person object without it internally fetching like the DAO? Or do I have it wrong and is it supposed to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've figured it out. Proxy objects CAN have a database connection. The only caveat is if the object gets serialized at a point in time bad things can happen, although I won't be doing that. What I did is have my Proxy pass in my DAO when you initialize it, a factory for the ease of object creation, and an internal instance of my object. Afterwards, the api must be similar to that of the object you proxy and all its calls will simply forward to the internal instance.